# How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python, for twitch?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, vertical-scrolling

I want to scroll vertical using Selenium.
I have read all the existing answers but non of them is working for the link
https://www.twitch.tv/directory/all

Kindly guide what is it about this page that makes the code

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080);")`

to have no effect at all.

Here is the complete code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sohaib/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/directory/all')
sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080);")
driver.quit()`
```

Comment: You wants to scroll Horizontal or Vertical ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @IshitaShah, I want to scroll vertical.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I am looking for the approach that can be used to scroll a page using Selenium. Many have suggested to use driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080);") which is not working for link I have provided in the question, I am not sure if that has something to do with the structure of the page.

Comment: @SohaibAslam What happens when you use that?

Comment: @DebanjanB, The code seems to be working for other sites. But for page : https://www.twitch.tv/directory/all it has no effect at all. NOTHING happens page stays at its position.

Comment: @DebanjanB, yeah, thanks for helping me correct the question. :)
Could you please upvote my question I only need +5 point to gain enough points to upvote answers? I'd be great help.

Comment: @DebanjanB, would it break for some cases? How come this solution cannot be considered as part of learning Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for vertical scroll,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# Selects the first preview card
card = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-a-target="preview-card-title-link"]')
card.send_keys(Keys.END) # Add a while loop to do infinite scroll
```

Comment: This is not working, and I am not sure why is would work?

Comment: I just tested it, it works fine, its doing vertical scroll, are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes it worked, I must have tested it wrong earlier. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How would I stop the iteration in while loop. How can I detect the end of page, any ideas on that?

Comment: I cannot upvote the answers yet, I still need +2 points for that, if you were to upvote my question I'll get the required points and will then upvote the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to use vertical scroll, You can use window.scrollBy(0,200) too,

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1080)")
```

You may try with JavaScriptExecutor as well,

```
js.execute_Script("window.scrollBy(0,1080)")
```